# Auto calculate difference of year and month using javascript in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The code below shows the HTML and the javascript of my code, I've created a dynamic table which will allow the user to add and remove the row of table dynamically. What I'm trying to do now is the auto calculation of two date (Month and Year only). The duration table are not responsive at all after I've select the month and year between the date.

Javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var h = 0;
    
    function history() {
    h++;
    var copyContent= "<tr><td><input class='tableBody' type='month' id='from"+h+"' name='from[]' autocomplete='off' required></td>";
        copyContent += "<td><input class='tableBody' type='month' id='to"+h+"' name='to[]' autocomplete='off' required></td>";
        copyContent += "<td><input class='tableBody' type='text' id='duration"+h+"' name='duration[]' autocomplete='off' required></td>";
        copyContent += "<td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='reason[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>";
        copyContent += "<td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='other[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>";
        copyContent += "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove' style='cursor:pointer'><i class='material-icons' title='Delete item'>remove_circle_outline</i></a></td></tr>";
        $('#tbl_history').append(copyContent);

        document.getElementById("h").value = h;
    }
        
//duration calculation
$('#from[]').change(function() {

    ToDate.min = document.getElementById('from0').value;
    var start = new Date(document.getElementById('from0').value);
    var end = new Date(document.getElementById('to').value);
    var duration = new Date();

    var different = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    // duration = (different/(1000*60*60*24))+1;
    duration = (new Date(start), new Date(end));
    document.getElementById('duration').value = duration;


        document.getElementById('duration').value = (start, end);
    
});


$('#ToDate').change(function() {
    var start = new Date(document.getElementById('from').value);
    var end = new Date(document.getElementById('to').value);
    var duration = new Date();

    var different = end.getTime() - start.getTime();
    // duration = (different/(1000*60*60*24))+1;
    duration = (new Date(start), new Date(end));
    document.getElementById('duration').value = duration;

        document.getElementById('duration').value = (start, end);
    
});



});

       
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="tbl_history" style="margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;">
    <tr class="tableTitle">
        <th><center>From</th>
        <th><center>To</th>
        <th style="width:150px;"><center>Duration</th>
        <th><center>Reason</th>
        <th><center>Other>
    </tr>
    <br/>                                               
    <tr>
        <td><input class="tableBody" type="month" id="from0" name="from[]" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td><input class="tableBody" type="month" id="to0" name="to[]" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td><input class="tableBody" type="text" id="duration0" name="duration[]" autocomplete="off" required></td>
        <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='reason[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
        <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='other[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="margin-right:-1200px">
   <a onclick="history()" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="material-icons" title="Add item">add_circle_outline</i></a> 
</div> 
<input name="h" type="text" id="h" readonly hidden>
```

Comment: The above Javascript has errors. Is this the actual code?

Comment: You cannot put a `<br/>` tag in the table at the location you have. You also cannot add `DIV` elements into the table as you are trying to do

Comment: Will this affect the thing that I'm trying to do ?

Comment: The errors in the Javascript will prevent it from working correctly/at all and the HTML issue will have no discernible effect but is invalid markup.

Comment: The `duration` value that you hope to calculate - is that to be calculated in seconds or some other unit of time - like days perhaps?

Comment: I would like to calculate it in months and years only, as you can see the type of my input is month

Comment: I rolled back your edit which essentially had become my answer and edited your original question to incorporate the changes that you referred to which were causing issues. I believe that it is incorrect to edit the question to such a degree that it is no longer recognisable from it's original form and is based upon an answer provided. The answer I gave has been edited in accordance to factor in these additional fields and work as per the original - the wrapping of the entire javascript in an anonymous event handling function however was totally removed as it served no discernible purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I do not use `jQuery` I offer instead a vanilla Javascript alternative that uses [delegated event listeners](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) to process the various events which we are interested in - namely the `change` event of the date fields and possibly the `click` event of the removal hyperlink.

```js
/*
  global variable that will store values from all input elements
  of type "month"
*/
var rows={};


/*
  Utility function that works it's way UP the DOM
  tree until a node of a particular type is found
  or returns false if not found. Useful to find a
  particular parent node.
*/
const getparent=(e,tag)=>{
  let n=e.target;
  while( n.tagName.toUpperCase()!=tag.toUpperCase() ){
    if( n.nodeName==='BODY' )return false;
    n=n.parentNode;
  }
  return n;
};

/*
  rudimentary date difference calculations
  - crude but illustrative. Will return 
  the number of years, months & total days
*/
const datedifference=(d1,d2)=>{
  return {
    y:Math.abs( d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear() ),
    m:Math.abs( d2.getMonth() - d1.getMonth() ),
    d:( Math.abs( ( d2 - d1 ) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) ) )
  }
};





/*
  Bind a "delegated" event listener to the table itself but
  process only events that satisfy the given criteria - ie:
  input elements of type "month" will fire the event handler
  code. Any other source will be disregarded. 
*/
document.getElementById('tbl_history').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.nodeType==1 && e.target.tagName=='INPUT' && e.target.type=='month' ){
    /*
      find the table row - it has the dataset attribute that makes
      working with the `rows` object easier.
    */
    let parent=getparent(e,'tr');
    
    /*
      Find the input element that will display 
      the calculated date difference.
      
      Explicitly target the duration field with it's name
    */
    let duration=parent.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="duration[]"]');
    
    /*
      find the row index
    */
    let row=parent.dataset.row;
    
    /*
      create new object per table row
      and store input value
    */
    if( !rows.hasOwnProperty( row ) )rows[ row ]={};
    rows[ row ][ e.target.name ]=e.target.value;

    /*
      Once both input elements have a value we
      can do the date difference calculations
      and display the value.
    */
    if( Object.keys( rows[ row ] ).length==2 ){
      let keys=Object.keys( rows[ row ] );
      let d1=new Date( rows[ row ][ keys[0] ] );
      let d2=new Date( rows[ row ][ keys[1] ] );

      let obj=datedifference(d1,d2);
      duration.value=[ obj.y+'yrs', obj.m+'months' ].join(', ');
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById('tbl_history').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.nodeType==1 && e.target.tagName=='I' ){
    let p=getparent(e,'tr');
      p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
  }
});




/*
  Essentially the same except for the removal of ID attributes, 
  the removal of the incorrect DIV elements and using template 
  literals rather than string concatenation. Oh and no jQuery.
  
  Additional columns now added to this function and the initial table.
*/
var h=0;
function history() {
  h++;
  var html = `
  <tr data-row='${h}'>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='month' name='from[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='month' name='to[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='duration[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
      <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='reason[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
      <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='other[]' autocomplete='off' /></td>
    <td>
      <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove' style='cursor:pointer'>
        <i class='material-icons' title='Delete item'>remove_circle_outline</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>`;
  
  document.getElementById('tbl_history').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',html);
  document.getElementById('h').value=h;
}
```

```css
#tbl_history > tr > th{
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table id='tbl_history' style='margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;'>
  <tr class='tableTitle'>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
    <th>Reason</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
    <!--

    do not add <br /> tags within the table body!!
    Removed ID attributes from input elements and
    added data-row attribute to table row element.

    -->
  <tr data-row='0'>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='month' name='from[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='month' name='to[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='duration[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='reason[]' autocomplete='off' required /></td>
    <td><input class='tableBody' type='text' name='other[]' autocomplete='off' /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div style='margin-right:-1200px'>
   <a onclick='history()' style='cursor:pointer'>
  <i class='material-icons' title='Add item'>add_circle_outline</i>
   </a> 
</div>

<input name='h' type='text' id='h' value=0 readonly hidden />
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the clear explanation on the code. May i know what if i have a few more input column (<td>) at the back of duration that has to be key in, because after user key in the value of the other column the value of months and year will automatically become NAN

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand your comment ~ can you clarify for me please? Can you add some HTML to accurately illustrate your actual scenario?

Comment: Hi, i had edited you code above. That is what I meant, I don't know why after the user key in some value in the "reason" or "other" column the duration value will become NaN

Comment: please refer to my edited code, Thank you

Comment: The reason lies in the use of `querySelector` within the event handler. It targeted what was the only text field in the ow - since additional input elements were added this querySelector call needed to be more precise - thus the `name` was added to the expression.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. I've found a minor bugs for the auto calculation of duration, if user select "to" date and then select "from" date the duration will become negative value

Comment: Simple fix: add `Math.abs()` around the returned values in the admittedly crude `datedifference` function. There are various ways this might be improved - like checking that the `from` date is before the `to` date perhaps